# How to normalise IPv6 address in Java?

Tags: java, ip, ipv6

Given a string which contains an IPv6 address in one of it's formats, is there a Java standart way to normalise it in a way that the same normalised value for different formats of the same address?
i.e

```
normalise("2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1") = x
normalise("2001:db8::1:0:0:1") = x
normalise("2001:db8:0:0:1::1") = x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this easily
by parsing the string with [`InetAddress.getByName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName-java.lang.String-)
and then converting back to string with [`getHostAddress()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress--):

```
public static String normalize(String s) throws UnknownHostException {
    return InetAddress.getByName(s).getHostAddress();
}
```

This method returns `"2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1"` for all your 3 examples.

By the way: The code above can normalize IPv6 *and* IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Unfortunately, this can trigger a DNS lookup if the string is not an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The [open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) provides various methods for different string formats.  Several can be used to produce a normalized string.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of the IPAddress library.

Two that are well-suited to be considered "standardized" strings are the canonical string and the normalized string.

The canonical string is the recommended way of writing IPv6 addresses as defined by [RFC 5952](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Recommended_representation_as_text)

The normalized string is the format produced by the class java.net.InetAddress.

```
static void printNormalized(String strs[]) {
    for (String str : strs) {
        System.out.println(new IPAddressString(str).getAddress().toNormalizedString());
    }
}

static void printCanonical(String strs[]) {
    for (String str : strs) {
        System.out.println(new IPAddressString(str).getAddress().toCanonicalString());
    }
}

String strs[] = {
    "2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1",
    "2001:db8::1:0:0:1", 
    "2001:db8:0:0:1::1"};

printCanonical(strs);
System.out.println();
printNormalized(strs);
```

Output:

```
2001:db8::1:0:0:1
2001:db8::1:0:0:1
2001:db8::1:0:0:1

2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1
2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1
2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1
```